# Need to Sort through a Dictionary based on specific Parameters

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, parameters

I found a good Sorting method but then realized I did not have the specific details of what to sort by included.

So far I have:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, ColorType>> myList = map.ToList();

        myList.Sort(
            delegate (KeyValuePair<int, ColorType> pair1,
            KeyValuePair<int, ColorType> pair2)
            {
                return pair1.Value.CompareTo(pair2.Value);
            }
        );
```

I need to sort by:

1: Sort list numbers ascending and by colors Red < Yellow < White

How can I apply these specifications?

Comment: Don't use `CompareTo` in your `Comparison<T>` delegate.  Use `If` statements and explicitly return 1, 0 or -1 based on the two values `ColorType` values.

Comment: Assuming `map` is a `Dictionary<int, ColorType>`, sorting by anything other than the key is superfluous because you can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: If you really want to use `CompareTo` then that `ColorType` type would have to implement `IComparable` and that implementation would have to compare the values in the same way as you'd have to compare them in your own delegate..

Comment: Yes Map is Dictionary. I have a list of numbers that are shuffled then have color assigned to them sequentially Red, Yellow, White going down throughout the list. Then entries are removed by even numbers that are Red, odd numbers that are Yellow and numbers divisible by three that are white. The remaining list items that I have now need to be sorted by the numbers ascending and then by the colors in that order Red<Yellow<White. Is that possible? Or are only the numbers or the Colors able to be sorted? Or maybe I would have to have two separate print outs